# In Shor's algorithm, why do we have ${\rm gcd}(x\pm 1, N) > 1$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, shors-algorithm, factorization

I'm struggling to understand the last part of Shor's algorithm, to be exact the point when we found $x-1$, $x+1$ with $x-1 ≠ 0\mod N$, $x+1 ≠ 0 \mod N$ and $(x+1)(x-1) = 0 \mod N$.

Then, $gcd(x-1, N) > 1$ and $gcd(x+1, N) > 1$ should hold true. Why is this the case? Is this so trivial to see? Especially the$\mod N$ confuses me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumptions $x\pm1\neq0\bmod N$ mean that neither of them is a multiple of (or equal to) $N$. That is, you cannot write $x+1=kN$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and same for $x-1$.

At the same time, $(x+1)(x-1)=0\bmod N$ means that $(x+1)(x-1)=kN$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. This means all factors of $N$ are contained in this product. But by the previous assumption, they are not contained in $x+1$ or $x-1$ individually. So the only possibility is that *some* of the factors of $N$ are in $x+1$, and some of them are in $x-1$.
This is equivalent to saying that the GCD between $x\pm1$ and $N$ is not one.

As an example, consider a simple case with $N=pq$ with $p,q$ coprimes. Then if $(x+1)(x-1)=kpq$ but $x\pm1\neq0\bmod pq$, then $x+1$ must contain $p$, and $x-1$ must contain $q$ (or vice versa).
And that would mean $\operatorname{gcd}(x+1,N)=p>1$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(x+1,N)=q>1$.